How to create a "multi-node" (node=machine) Kubernetes/Kubeflow cluster for Machine Learning Training?
I have multiple computers/machines. Each computer/machine has multiple GPUs. I am currently training my machine learning model using tensorflow. I can train on a single machine/computer, or I can use TF's MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy to synchronously train with all the computers/machines. (Each machine/computer has it's own data, computes it's own gradients, and they aggregate in sync)
Given that I have multiple computers/machines, I would obviously like to create a cluster and use all of their GPU's collectively. Unfortunately, it does not seem possible to virtually collect GPU's from multiple computers/machines onto one single computer/machine.
It seems my only option to use the collective power of all the GPU's from all my machines is to distribute the training to different computers/machines and aggregate results. If the size of my model becomes too large, then the only option would be to distribute my model itself.
Kubernetes is a cluster in the respect that you can deploy multiple packages (pods) within a single computer/machine, across multiple computers/machines. But it does not seem to allow for deployment of a single process across multiple computers/machines?
In my situation the ideas regarding pods seem useless to me. I would want my pod to encompass all my computers/nodes/machines. But considering that's not possible the best I can do is extend the pod over all the GPU's on a single machine? So one pod would equal one node. I see no function in distributing my training any further than necessary to multiple pods within a single machine.
So, at this point, I just want a kubernetes cluster that can be used for distributed training with each of my
computers/machines added as a node/pod.
It seems if I just had a Kubernetes or Microk8s cluster thats not pre-configured for training distribution I'd have to figure out how to aggregate things manually.
Kubeflow seems to provide a method, are there any other methods for large model training with kubernetes?
Kubeflow provides Pytorch/Tensorflow/etc methods using training operator SDK to read your PytorchJob/TensorflowJob and distribute your training to replicas. It doesn't seem to provide a way to distribute it to your multiple machines though? Just pods within a single machine? So wouldn't even work with Tensorflows MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy on multiple machines?
Thanks everyone for taking the time to read - any help/ideas/links or support would be greatly appreciated.
Best,
I feel like I've read the entire Kubernetes webpage, and all the other kubernetes versions webpages. I was expecting compute unification, not just a list of GPU's that you can run independent processes on as long as the GPU's running a single process aren't split on different machines? I believe that is the extent of Kubernetes capabilities? Please correct me if Im wrong.
Thanks again,

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

There's more than one question, I've already made my issue clear and provided enough detail
